# How DoublyLinkedList (princeton version) remove method works?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to understand how [**DoublyLinkedList.java**](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/DoublyLinkedList.java.html) works as princeton version. Please click hype-link to get details.

But after long time, I still have two questions to fully understand this implementation.

Question 1: How if-else block in remove method works ? When will if branch happen ?

```
    // remove the element that was last accessed by next() or previous()
    // condition: no calls to remove() or add() after last call to next() or previous()
    public void remove() { 
        if (lastAccessed == null) throw new IllegalStateException();
        Node x = lastAccessed.prev;
        Node y = lastAccessed.next;
        x.next = y;
        y.prev = x;
        n--;

        // Below if-else condition I don't understand on which situation
        // "current == lastAccessed" will happen ?
        if (current == lastAccessed)
            current = y;
        else
            index--;
        lastAccessed = null;
    }
```

Question 2: For a fully functional DoublyLinkedList, we should also contain add or remove node at specific position, e.g `add(int index)` or `remove(int index)`, but in princeton version I could not find any hint on this part, so how could I implement such two method ? Could someone post some detail ? (Note: This version is using an `ListIterator`)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi, @Joe C, I am not a student anymore, just interest in this code, I can find other implementation of DoublyLinkedList easily, but as I learn data structure by myself after working hours, I would like to know the two question above, as the original code doesn't have enough hint on these two parts and implement not quite similar as Java stand library, thanks.

Comment: The add/remove/set are implemented on the iterator. You can simply add convenience methods to the class itself if you need them there (in practice, don't use this implementation). The if condition distinguishes between a remove called after a call to `previous` or `next`. The else branch covers the `next` case.

Comment: @pvg, thank you for your comment, I already test as you said, what you said exactly right, the if-else condition in `remove()` prepared for both `previous()` and `next()` call on purpose. When we call `previous()` before `remove()`, we go to if branch, when we call `next()` before `remove()`, we go to else branch.

Comment: Sedgewick's book is really more about the description and analysis of algos and less about the implementation. This isn't very good Java code (people used to say that about the C version of the book too) and I wouldn't rely on it on learning how to write such a structure well.

Comment: You should [check this out](https://www.cpp.edu/~ftang/courses/CS240/lectures/dlist.htm) for a better implementation. Also, don't be discouraged to **continue** reading Sedgewick's book. It's a great book to learn the inner workings of data structures and algorithms

Comment: Thank you guys, Sedgewick's book already give me great help, also, @RafiduzzamanSonnet, your link really helpful

Comment: @Lampard Check out my  answer

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet, yeah, already tried your answer, after import the index, it works well, many thanks

Comment: @Lampard You should accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet, hi, Rafi, sorry for that, I just select the check, and thank you, quite new to options on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pvg said, the implementation is completely up to the user and the requirements. Also, is not a very good implementation of **DoublyLinkedLists**.

**Answer 1**: Say you add 5 items in the list: 3, 2, 53, 23, 1. Then do the following without calling `next()` or `previous()` first:

```
iterator.remove();
```

It will throw `IllegalStateException` because `lastAccessed` is null. Why is it null? It's null because `lastAccessed` is updated in `next()` and `previous()` only. You haven't **accessed** any nodes by calling `next()` or `previous()`.

**Answer 2**: You can add by passing the index AND the reference of the node to be added.

```
public void add(int index, Node item) {
    if (index > size) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    Node cursor = head.next;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < index) {
        i++;
        cursor = cursor.next;
    }

    item.next = cursor.next;
    item.next.prev = item;
    cursor.next = item;
    item.prev = cursor;
    size++;
}
```

For the `remove()` function, you can implement this: `remove(int index)`. Just traverse through the list with an `int i=0` until `i < index` and then remove the node. This will take O(n) time. Or the easier way could be to just pass the reference to the node to be deleted. And this will take O(1).

The implementation depends on what your requirements are. If you need to remove by index and you don't have the reference to the node, then you must traverse the list. Or just pass the reference of the node to be deleted:

```
public void remove(Node item) {
    Node prev = item.prev;
    Node next = item.next;

    prev.next = next;
    next.prev = prev;

    item.next = null;
    item.prev = null;
}
```